# Run Python file after specific read from SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to Python. I'm learning day by day the features and seems to be unlimited.

I've managed to start having my SQL data extracted via Python with 'Windows Task Scheduler' selecting a specific time for the .py file to run.

However, sometimes the data is not yet loaded at the time I have on the 'Windows Task Scheduler' and this may result on querying the wrong data or having duplication.

This means, I have a SQL query to check if the data has been loaded or not.

Similar to this:

```
SEL LOAD_DATE , MAX(CASE WHEN LOAD_ID = X THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END)  WHATEVERNAME 
From DATABASE 
WHERE LOAD_DATE = CURRENT_DATE
```

My question is, is is possible to run a python file whenever the printing for this query is 'TRUE'?
This means, I want the result of this query to trigger all the other queries to start, and prevent to have the data extracted if the data load is delayed for some reason.

I found this that could adapt to me and run the SQL code every 15 minutes until I get the true. My question is how do I make the the other files running form there?

```
import schedule
import time

def foo():
    print('do something')

schedule.every(28).minutes.do(foo)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Than you all

Comment: Why do you want it to be scheduled in windows scheduler ? Cant it be written as a long running python application which can wait for 28 mins, check the query and then initiate further executions via  a thread or so ?

Comment: I recommend instead to have the python script run the SQL then do what you need to do in python. Schedule this python script instead of the SQL.

Comment: Schedule One script to run every 15 minutes or whatever, and have that One script run the SQL -and- run the business process (once the sql has finished).

Comment: @Kris, I want to get rid of windows scheduler

Comment: @MatBailie that's is what I plan to do, question is how can I run the business process based on the SQL answer. this means, if FALSE I want it to run again until I get TRUE. Once I get TRUE I want it to stop and run the business processes. Does it makes sense?